# What are internal and external estimates of error?

Tags: terminology, definition, error-analysis, experimental-technique, data-analysis

I have *n* measurements for a quantity, and I need to calculate the internal and external estimates of error. I know what standard error is and how it is calculated, but have no clue regarding internal and external estimates.

Comment: found this https://cosmognosis.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/internal-vs-external-uncertainties-again/

Comment: About your question, I am also not so sure and even more to comment you need 50 rep. I have no idea on my rep, haha! Here's what I found on the site(while Googling) - https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Summary-of-Internal-Error-External-Error-Measurement-Repeatability-and-Accuracy-for_tbl1_248802490 There is a table I found regarding *Relative External Error* and *Relative Internal Error* and I will make an assumption, that it **probably relates** to the *Minimum Error* and the *Maximum Error* **respectively**. Forgive me because I can't explain exactly as to why I assumed something [...]

Comment: [...] like that after seeing the table once.

I am not 1000% sure on my answer as it is my assumption so I hope someone corrects me.

Answer (score 0):

Section 6 of the article [Nakajima et al] [1] quoted by @AshCAD defines what these authors mean by internal and external errors.

It would appear that internal errors and those associated with the raw data whereas external errors are those associated with parameters which are used to analyse the data.

I think this terminology is non-standard and needs to be defined within any article using the terms.

[1]  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248802490_Improved_Limb_Atmospheric_Spectrometer_ILAS_data_retrieval_algorithm_for_Version_520_gas_profile_products

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that it is more common to call these "statistical error" and "non-sampling error".

The "statistical error" describes the uncertainty within the dataset. E.g. if we fit a linear regression model, it is possible to determine the statistical uncertainty for each fit parameter. Thus, this is "just" mathematics.

However, there is a second uncertainty components, which is not governed by mathematics. E.g. if we measure the flux of gamma radiation coming from the sun the result depends on the solar activity. Thus, if we measure the flux during an inactive time period, our dataset might tell us that the flux is rather constant. Thus, we have to include the "non-sampling error" to either increase our uncertainty, or (better) to use a model to stratisfy our result.

PS: I'm not an expert in the subject matter of gamma ray flux.